# Can I use vscode to connect to a remote machine to compile and debug

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a few linux machines that I'd like some students to use to compile and run their code in C++ using only the console for input and output.

Ideally, I'd like them to be able to use vscode to edit their code on their native platform and then use the linux machines to compile and run. This will solve the problem of not all the students having access to the same tools.

However, it would also be nice if they could use vscode as a debugging tool to access the remote server running their code. Is this possible? If so, are there some instructions on how to set up the client and server machines?

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to X11 forwarding? Use all tools on server machine, and just display any GUI application on the client machine? I've used vscode over ssh and it works fairly well.

Comment: Any special setup or vscode config required? What about debugging using vscode?